# On conversion of HTML to PDF using itext having <li> tag the last line is not present in the PDF

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext

Hi am converting html to PDF using itext and am using listtag to display my list, but in the PDF created the last line is always getting cut.
This is the Html that I am using:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Roadmap</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table class = "table2" style="border-spacing: 10px;padding: 10px;background:#f2f2f2; border:1px solid black;width:100%;color:white;font-family:'arial(body)',tahoma,arial, sans-serif;">
         <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width:20%;padding:10px;background-color:#82bc00">
               <ul style="margin:-15px;list-style-type: disc;">
                  <li style="padding:7px;line-height:1.2em;font-size:15px;font-weight: bold;">AQE - PMS</li>
                  <li style="padding:7px;line-height:1.2em;font-size:15px;font-weight: bold;">Data - Stabilization</li>
                  <li style="padding:7px;line-height:1.2em;font-size:15px;font-weight: bold;">PMS Serverization</li>
               </ul>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="width:20%;padding:10px;background-color:#f8971d">
               <ul style="margin:-15px;list-style-type: disc;">
                  <li style="padding:7px;line-height:1.2em;font-size:15px;font-weight: bold;">Instamatic Rollout</li>
                  <li style="padding:7px;line-height:1.2em;font-size:15px;font-weight: bold;">Rollout of GR Sectoring Server</li>
                  <li style="padding:7px;line-height:1.2em;font-size:15px;font-weight: bold;">SEC Liquidity Risk Management</li>
               </ul>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="width:20%;padding:10px;background-color:#13b5ea">
               <ul style="margin:-15px;list-style-type: disc;">
                  <li style="padding:7px;line-height:1.2em;font-size:15px;font-weight: bold;">BRSRE Enhancements</li>
                  <li style="padding:7px;line-height:1.2em;font-size:15px;font-weight: bold;">Risk Reporting Support</li>
                  <li style="padding:7px;line-height:1.2em;font-size:15px;font-weight: bold;">Sectoring - Product Management</li>
               </ul>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image: This is the PDF which I am getting]

The last line management is not shown in the PDF.
Thanks for the help.

My JAVA code is: `{

```
        // writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
        // writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteArrayOutputStream);
        document.open();
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new StringReader(htmlString));
        document.close();
        byte[] pdfBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        return pdfBytes;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.info("File Cannot be created");
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}`
```

Comment: Have you tried this with iText 7 + pdfHTML? See https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML and https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml I'm asking because support on iText 5 + XML Worker is being phased out, and you may not get any answer on your question. If possible, you should always use the latest version of iText. If not possible, e.g. because iText 5 is already in your code base for a long time, your company probably has a commercial license (it should) and in that case, please create a support ticket on the closed ticketing system.